# c++ converting \r\n in an input string to carriage return and newline

Tags: c++, string, printf, scanf

I need to convert an input string which can contain \r\n as part of string. For example as given below

```
\r\n Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n Subject: Test Subject \r\n\r\n Test Message
```

Now while sending this string over HTTP Post data I need to convert \r\n to percentile encoding. But when I use curl_easy_escape function it understand \r\n as different characters and encode incorrectly. So to avoid such error I need to convert \r\n in above string as carriage return and newline so that the buffer get converted correctly by curl_easy_escape() function.
I tried using sstream object, sprintf and sscanf with the buffer (as the buffer is an std::string object) but didn't help out much. Basically I want to convert the buffer as below

Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
 Subject: Test Subject

Test Message

So that when we pass this buffer to curl_easy_escape it encodes properly. 
So any pointers in this regard will be very helpful.

Comment: What result you expect? "curl_easy_escape function it understand \r\n as different characters" - they **are** different characters.

Comment: @Kiril Basically I want to convert the buffer as below

 Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
 Subject: Test Subject

 Test Message

So that curl_easy_escape can encode correctly. The output is missing new lines and carriage returns.

Comment: the way you convert *anything* to percent encoding is to take *each* character and convert it. `\r\n` are *two* characters, so to convert them, you do exactly what curl does: convert one character, then convert the other character. If you want something else, then show us *exactly* what a `\r\n` should look like after encoding.

Comment: I want to convert the buffer as below

`
 Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
 Subject: Test Subject

 Test Message`
So that the buffer can be encoded properly.

Comment: Noboody understands your definition of "correctly" or "properly". Give an example, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) in a loop to do it:

```
std::string input = "\\r\\n Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 \\r\\n Subject: Test Subject \\r\\n\\r\\n Test Message";

std::string::size_type pos = 0;
while ((pos = input.find("\\r\\n", pos)) != std::string::npos)
{
    input.replace(pos, 4, "\r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<regex>` members if you have access to them:

```
std::string const input("abcd\\r\\nefgh\\r\\nijkl");
std::string const output(std::regex_replace(input, std::regex("\\\\r\\\\n"), std::string("\r\n")));
```